# dskchk hanging at ~50% when scanning a corrupt MicroSD

Tags: formatting, sd-card, chkdsk, flashing

I have a SanDisk Ultra 32GB MicroSD that is clearly corrupted. I cannot delete files from it. Formatting fails.

I tried to run `chkdsk r/` but it stops and hangs at about 50% after finding a few corrupt files. During `chkdsk` it reports that it finds and replaces corrupt files but I think the latter is untrue as the errors persist across scans.

Are there any other tools I can use to rebuild the SD and save it?

Comment: "It's worse than that, it's dead, Jim" [this is nearly as bad as a Rick Roll, but go look anyway, if you don't get the reference.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCARADb9asE) Whether it's a fake 32GB or not, it's dead. Throw it away & get a new one - from somewhere *different*.

Comment: A 32GB card is not worth the time or effort to recover.